# Name of git plugin/enhancement to add numbers to git results

Tags: git

I recently had to wipe my computer and lost some of the config I had there.

One thing I'm missing is a plugin/enhancement I had on git that would, among other things, add numbers to certain git commands results so that you could reference those instead of file or branch names.

For instance, running `git branch` would return something like:

```
> git branch
[1] master
[2] my-feature
[3] another-test
```

and I could do something like:

```
git checkout 1
```

and it will be equivalent to

```
git checkout master
```

Any idea what the name of this plugin/enhancement was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Not sure how it took me so long to find this in Google

https://github.com/scmbreeze/scm_breeze